# java forcing compile-time evaluation

Tags: java, bytecode, compile-time

In java, is there a general way to enforce compile-time compilation? In a programming competition I'm in we are limited by the bytecode our robot can use every round while the program is running, so if I'm able to compute things at compile time I have an advantage.

For a concrete example, lets say I want to define a variable NORTH that will be an array of 
MapLocations representing the squares the robot can see if facing North. If I hand code this,
I can write:

```
public class SightSensor{
  public static MapLocation[] NORTH = {new MapLocation(-2,2),
                    new MapLocation(-1,1),
                        new MapLocation(-1,2),
                        new MapLocation(0,1),
                        new MapLocation(0,2),
                        new MapLocation(0,3),
                        new MapLocation(1,1),                       
                        new MapLocation(1,2),
                        new MapLocation(2,2)};
```

}

which represents that the robot can see all squares in a 90 degree arc about due north within a distance squared of 9. Now, my robots can see in all cardinal directions, and some can see farther
than others. It would be rather tedious and seemingly bad form to hand code each possible
sight (distance, direction) pair. Hence, I wrote a function

```
public static MapLocation[] getSensorLocs(int r, Direction dir){ ... bla ... }
```

that automatically computes the locations, so I can re-write the SightSensor class as

```
public class SightSensor{
  public static MapLocation[] NORTH = getSensorLocs(3, Direction.NORTH);
}
```

The only problem is now when by robot tries to use the NORTH variable, it has to spend the 
time to run the getSensorLocs method, so it is more expensive than the hand-written version.
Can I force that computation to be run at compile-time, i.e. be "symbolically replaced" in an appropriate sense?

Comment: I think you are looking for a compile-time pre-processor, similar to that in C?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I understand you are optimising for bytecode size, you can use the following approach.

```
// 8 bytes per field.
public static MapLocation[] NORTH = locations("\u006a\u0079\u007a\u0089\u008a\u008b\u0099\u009a\u009b\u00aa");

// 57 bytes.
public static MapLocation[] locations(String s) {
    final int len = s.length();
    MapLocation[] locations = new MapLocation[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        locations[i] = new MapLocation((ch >> 4) - 8, (ch & 0xf) - 8);
    }
    return locations;
}

static class MapLocation {
    public MapLocation(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
    }
}
```

prints

```
x=-2, y=2
x=-1, y=1
x=-1, y=2
x=0, y=1
x=0, y=2
x=0, y=3
x=1, y=1
x=1, y=2
x=1, y=3
x=2, y=2
```

Note: the length of the encoding String doesn't add any byte code!.

---

When you run the first code it actually creates the array and each element at runtime. There is no compile time optimisation.  I suggest you check whether and why your `getSensorLocs` method is slower because it shouldn't be significantly slower.

Comment: The problem seems to be that he's running in an artificial environment where execution speed is tightly limited on the bytecode level, making lazily initialized stuff a real problem.

Comment: And I suspect he doesn't know its a problem, its just something he is used to doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, This looks like just the ticket! I'll look into it right now.

Comment: @andyInCambridge String literals are constants, unlike arrays which are built one elements at a time in byte code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`public static MapLocation[] NORTH = getSensorLocs(3, Direction.NORTH);` is already only evaluated once -- why would it run every time? you've already done the "precomputation".

I'm not sure if this is really a question of evaluation. You seem to want to run code at compile time, and that's not something any language does in general. Java does not have a pre-processor, which might be the closest sort of thing to what you mean. The most Java does are things like compute that the literal "5+3" is "8".

Comment: Sean, indeed I seem to want a pre-processor command. It seems sad that there is no way to achieve hand-coded speed. I could write a side program that calls the Construct-Sensor and then writes a new "hand-coded" SightSensor class for me, but that just seems ugly.

Comment: Many languages have features to run code at compile time, Lisp macros and C++ templates being the most prominent.

Comment: C++'s templates can essentially run code at compile time. I've heard of them being used to calculate (at compile time) prime numbers or pi or some such. But afaik, Java can't do that sort of fun stuff.

Comment: @yshavit, and Michael, Precisely. I'm a c++ programmer so I was hoping for something similar.

Comment: @andyInCambridge: no, I'm saying that you have already achieved what you seem to want to in your code. Accessing `NORTH` does *not* cause that method to be called. It is called once to initialize.

Comment: @andyInCambridge I am sure you are aware of premature optimisation.  Can you tell us how much difference it made in your tests when you compared the performance?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that the competition allows only so many bytecode ops per round, and I'm guessing you don't get a pre-round warmup phase. So even if the code executes really quickly and only once, the ops eat into OP's bytecode limit, and it would be nice to have them not do that if possible.

Comment: @Peter, yshavit is dead on. The optimization difference is considerable. My ConstructSensor function is as good as it can be (without effectively being hand-coded). Namely, something like 80 bytecode cost for the hand-coded versus 800 bytecode cost in the ConstructSensor() version. For reference, the bot gets 3000 bytecode per round -- so if I wanted to initialize all 8 directions, or even worse a longer sight range, you can see how this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not compile-time compilation you're asking for - it's compile-time execution.

What you're asking for is for NORTH to be somehow computed at compile time and then saved as a "frozen" value in the bytecode.

This is not in general possible or desirable.

If you're restricted by the amount of bytecode that you can use, then consider representing the directions etc not as objects, but as arrays of flags. This is basically writing old-school C code in Java, so not recommended as general best practice, but still quite common in games programming (especially on Java ME)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest you can get is to write an annotation processor that manipulates the code during compilation, the way it's done in [Project Lombok](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-lombok/index.html?ca=drs-). But that could be quite a lot of work, as it apparently uses non-public APIs of `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

You could in another java project write a code generator generating a .java file. Instead of all those `new MapLocation`'s you could reuse objects (`static final MapLocation ML_M2_1 = new MapLocation(-2, 1);`), which would help more. The only other way to tickle more speed out of all, is to consider that you are creating lookup data. If you succeed in creating a numeric coding like `0xF2` for `new MapLocation(-1, 2)` you would really have saved something.

Comment: Precisely. A code generator may be my only option. In essence I am asking how to build a highly efficient lookup table in Java. Do you know of any materials I might look at for reference?